# How to implement SQL where in for entity framework 6

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6, where-clause

I am trying to filter a dataset from entity framework table using the below functions. The issue I am experiencing is that when I get to .ToList() I get an object reference error. If I take out the .contains line the query works fine.

```
Public Function List(entityModel As String, filter As BO.Filter.Import) As IList(Of BO.Import)
    ' Get import data '
    Using context = New RBEntities
        Dim result = context.import_data.Where(Function(s) s.entity_model = entityModel)
        result = ApplyFilter(result, filter)

        Return result.Select(Function(s) New BO.Import(s)).ToList()
    End Using
End Function

Private Function ApplyFilter(result As IOrderedQueryable(Of import_data), filter As BO.Filter.Import) As IOrderedQueryable(Of import_data)
        If Not filter.IDs Is Nothing AndAlso filter.IDs.Count > 0 Then
            If Not filter.IDs(0) = -1 Then
                result = result.Where(Function(w) filter.IDs.Contains(CInt(w.id)))
            End If
        End If

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Term) Then
            result = result.Where(Function(w) w.data.ToLower().Contains(filter.Term.ToLower()))
        End If

        If Not filter.Status Is Nothing Then
            result = result.Where(Function(w) w.status = filter.Status)
        End If

        If filter.UserProfileID > 0 Then
            result = result.Where(Function(w) w.user_profile_id = filter.UserProfileID)
        End If

        Return result
    End Function
```

Comment: Here's a C# version: `persons.Where(p => list.Contains(p.PersonId))` becomes `select * from person where personid in (...)`

Comment: Don't put inside `IQuerable<T>` any .NET code such as `ToLower()`. It won't work in the most cases. And most probably isn't necessary.

Comment: I know the .contains works when using where on a normal list. The issue is when trying to do the same thing to filter a list of entities from entity framework e.g. list(of import_data) I get an object reference error. You C# example is what I am already doing.

Comment: In what line do you receive NullReferenceException?

Comment: result.Select(Function(s) New BO.Import(s)).ToList() but you can also get it by doing result.ToList()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve the issue by replacing the below

```
result = result.Where(Function(w) filter.IDs.Contains(CInt(w.id)))
```

with

```
result = result.Where(Function(w) filter.IDs.Any(Function(a) a = w.id))
```